# how to make repeat(circular) horizontal scrollview?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, circular-list

how to make horizontal scroll view repeat. I have list of views that pours from the server. if the list is ended then again starts from the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `listview`, way better for you in this case where you need memory management.

and for your adapter/listview you can use this

https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/circular-list-adapter

Comment: no, i do not want to use listview. my data is has two things and it only attach with view. so please tell me how to make it without adapter.

Comment: you can't just do a circular scrollview, it will have memory leaking issues, and I don't think you can do that, because basically the adapter just created Integer.MAX_VAUE elements, that's why it looks infinite when in reality it is not, this is why you can't create an infinite scroll view